# How to transform a query result to an array in Java

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons

I have a query result like this:

```
Date             Product   Quantity
01/01/2015       A         2
01/01/2015       B         3
02/01/2015       A         1
03/01/2015       B         4
```

Date and product has a variable length.

I want to achieve the following result array:

```
[
['Date'     , 'Product A', 'Product B'],
[01/01/2015 ,      2      , 3],
[02/01/2015 ,      1      , 0],
[03/01/2015 ,      0      , 4],
]
```

I can achieve the goal by using and algorithm but, is there a library that does this kind of staff, like guava or apache commons?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: can you add more code to see how you are getting this result, the type and so on?

Comment: What returns the query? If is data in a database? Or text in a tsv? Or something else?

Comment: What do you want to return value to be? If an array or arrays (as it look in this), do you want that as a Java array or as a text file?

Comment: Why an array? you will loose the typing of your data.

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries that generally create List of beans, not as array of arrays.

An example is [Spring JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)

Here is the example taken from spring jdbc documentation:

```
List<Actor> actors = this.jdbcTemplate.query(
        "select first_name, last_name from t_actor",
        new RowMapper<Actor>() {
            public Actor mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Actor actor = new Actor();
                actor.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
                actor.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
                return actor;
            }
        });
```

where `Actor` is the bean corresponding to a record of your query.